# Inserting data into MySQL table from netbeans: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: java, oracle, netbeans

Trying to populate a table in an oracle database when the java application starts

```
//Enter truck records into database
    public void insertTruck()
    {
        String sqlTruck = "";
        sqlTruck+= "INSERT INTO JAVAUSER.TRUCK (VINNUMBER, MAKE, MODEL, PURCHASEPRICE, LICENSENUMBER)"
                + "VALUES ('1458796523147856', 'Toyota', 'Corolla', '15000', 'HJY7854')"; 

        sqlTruck+= "INSERT INTO JAVAUSER.TRUCK (VINNUMBER, MAKE, MODEL, PURCHASEPRICE, LICENSENUMBER)"
                + "VALUES ('7895684252354123', 'Ford', 'F150', '11200', 'JGR5467')";

        sqlTruck+= "INSERT INTO JAVAUSER.TRUCK (VINNUMBER, MAKE, MODEL, PURCHASEPRICE, LICENSENUMBER)"
                + "VALUES ('7825462358422522', 'Ford', 'Focus', '11500', 'HJY7854')";
        sqlTruck+= "INSERT INTO JAVAUSER.TRUCK (VINNUMBER, MAKE, MODEL, PURCHASEPRICE, LICENSENUMBER)"
                + "VALUES ('6325412548225486', 'Ford', 'Mustang', '18000', 'JGR5467')";
        sqlTruck+= "INSERT INTO JAVAUSER.TRUCK (VINNUMBER, MAKE, MODEL, PURCHASEPRICE, LICENSENUMBER)"
                + "VALUES ('1254355985245522', 'Toyota', 'Prius', '13000', 'JGR5467')";
        sendDBCommand(sqlTruck);
    }
```

Comment: If you want to insert multiple records at once, the syntax is: `insert into table (col1, col2) values (1, 2), (3,4), (5,6)`

Comment: You need to execute N statements each containing 1 query. Not one statement containing N queries. Or do as juergen says.

Comment: Would the best way to do this be creating a method for inserting each query? then passing each individual string to the sendDBCommand method?

Comment: Why are you saying you are inserting into MySQL when you are clearly using Oracle? You need to call `executeUpdate()` once for each `INSERT` statement. You can execute more than one statement with a single JDBC `executeUpdate()` call